# Ложные срабатывания Windows Defender на программу C++

Tags: c++, qt, антивирус

У меня есть проект на C++ с использование Qt, я собирался уже выкладывать его на свой сайт и радоваться, но решил протестировать программу на других компьютерах и столкнулся с проблемой, что Windows Defender самый "лучший" антивирус детектит в моей программе троян... Вируса конечно же нет и в чем может быть проблема не понимаю, может есть какие-то компоненты в Qt или просто C++, которые вызывают ложные срабатывания? Из-за чего вообще это может произойти, и главный вопрос как сделать так чтобы эти ложные срабатывания перестали срабатывать!

Comment: Такое иногда случается, если Вы запускали не Release, а Debug версию.

Comment: да в том то и дело что версия то Release... И Debug я тоже пробовал, ошибки не происходит, получается все наоборот, но появляется очевидная ошибка с библиотеками mscvp140.dll и все в этом духе

Comment: есть десятки вариантов. К примеру, программа может содержать подозрительный текст (подозрительные ключи реестра), а может и на самом деле делает что то не очень хорошее

Comment: можете рассказать свои предположения? и кратко объяснить как это можно исправить?

Comment: Видимо ваша программа не содержит цифровой подписи или не является широко распространенной. Соответственно подписывайте свою программу, делайте ее распространённой, присылайте на валидацию до публикации.

Comment: Ну чтоб перестали - поясните ему, что проверять в каталогах, где вы программируете, не следует, что вы зуб даете, что там чисто :)

Comment: а как это сделать? Можно ссылки на ресурсы, я попадался на цифровую подпись, но не особо понял как она работает и как именно подписывать, как пояснить что проверять в каталогах, как это сделать? Я не попался ни на один источник