# VirusTotal ругается на программу после компиляции

Tags: c++, компиляция, exe, вирусы, антивирус

Недавно начал изучение C++ и решил скомпилировать первую программу, обычный Hello world. Ради интереса закинул этот exe на [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/), он пишет, что обнаружено 8 угроз. Также Windows defender удаляет этот файл и пишет, что это троян. Почему так, и как это исправить? Сама программа:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

Скриншот из VirusTotal:

[image: скрин из вирус тотала]

Comment: Выкинуть глючный антивирус (лучше вместе со всеми его создателями и пользователями)

Comment: Это "нормально", так бывает с мелкими программами.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214099/#comment2122636_1214099

Comment: да это обычная практика ;) У меня Касперский стоит, тоже иногда ругается на компилируемые файлы. Особенно когда там выделение памяти большое идет. У меня все проекты на Си лежат в одной папке, я в Касперском добавил эту папку в исключения. И проблема пропала. Для проектов на Дэлфи тоже самое было, тоже добавил папку в исключения. В вашем антивирусе эта функция должна быть тоже. Добавьте папку проектов в исключения антивируса. Гугл в помощь как это сделать ;)

Comment: Какие-то там сомнительные антивирусы ругаются - забить на них.

Comment: Если экзешник имеет очень маленький размер, то многие антивирусы автоматически будут считать его вредноносным ПО. Обычно этот порог - несколько килобайт. Исторически так сложилось, что всякие вирусы, кряки, кигены писались на ассемблере, и их размер редко превышал десяток килобайт. Вот в ативирях и прописали: всё что маленькое - вредняк! Возможно, ваш хелоуворлд как раз слишком маленький, добавьте в него что-нибудь. Например, в компиляторе MinGW наличие оператора `new` в коде - это сходу плюс 100 кБ балласта из ABI к весу программы. Попробуте, вдруг поможет))

Answer (score 0):

Это все Хеш-коллизия

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769420/antivirus-detecting-compiled-c-files-as-trojans

Лучший ответ с переводом:

> На самом деле это была какая-то коллизия хешей, компилятор не был
> заражен. Я менял строку в функции печати, как было предложено,
> несколько раз, даже добавляя разрывы строк, но каждый раз мой
> антивирус обнаруживал ее как вредоносное ПО. Я также попытался удалить
> некоторые строки кода (включения и печать), и он также обнаружил их
> как вредоносное ПО.
>
> Забавно, но когда я добавил в код еще строки , AV перестал
> распознавать его как вирус. Заставляет задуматься, как работает
> используемая хэш-функция и как она связана с реальным содержанием
> программ.
>
> Итак, решено, и все было хорошо, просто некоторая неряшливость AV
> (что, я думаю, имеет свои причины).

Comment: Антивирус ищет СИГНАТУРУ в файле. И если она совпадает с его базой, то тревога :)
При компиляции появляется екзешник, для антивируса это стресс =))) Как? откуда? никто ничего не копировал! Я за всем слежу! Откуда экзешник взялся!?!? Пааанннииикккааа ! Ну примерно так =)))

Comment: То что это написали на английском SO - не значит, что это правда.

Comment: Теперь топовый ответ уже другой :)

Comment: Ого, значит мне найти топовый ответ и изменить ответ?

Comment: Не надо тупо перепечатывать ответы, лучше сначала самому проверить.

Answer (score -2):

Мне кажется, вся ошибка в `void main()`. Обычно принято писать `int main()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

Сори, если чет не то, я сам начал на плюсах прогать 1,5 месяца назад:)

Comment: Да, я проверил в visual studio code. Он на это ругается

Comment: void main писать во-первых, можно, а во-вторых, подозреваю, что скомпилированная прога будет точно такой же.

Comment: Ага, антивирусы следят за соблюдением стандарта С++. :)

Comment: @Qwertiy по стандарту [нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/794522/176217). Только если расширение допускает.